# Regex para capturar palavras entre dois caracteres

Tags: javascript, regex

O meu problema é o seguinte:

```
let texto = "teste :1: e também teste :2:"
```

O que eu preciso fazer é basicamente pegar as posições onde aparecem estes caracteres `:1:` e `:2:` com regex, já que o que aparece entre os dois pontos é dinâmico.

Tentei `texto.match('^[:.:]$')`, mas não rolou (estou começando com regex).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **':(.*?):', 'g')** - Esta expressão significa basicamente:
>
> - `.` pega tudo na mesma linha, `*` encontra 0 ou mais ocorrências no texto, `?` Encontra o primeiro caractere ou os outros seguintes.
> - `'g'` retorna todos os resultados especificados encontrados não só o primeiro.

```js
let texto = "teste :1: e também teste :2:";
let regex = new RegExp(':(.*?):', 'g');
let resul;

while ((resul = regex.exec(texto))) {     

  console.log(resul[1]);   // mostra o que está entre os :
}
```

**OBS**: Referência muito boa pode ser vista [aqui](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: `RegExp` é mais util quando tem texto dinamico na regex, caso contrário é melhor usar um *regex literal*. No seu caso é mais direto fazer `let regex = /:(.*):/g`. E o `'g'` é de global

Comment: Isso aí. Valeu man!

Answer (score 12):

A [resposta do @LeAndrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/312815/112052) explica muito bem como resolver o problema. Gostaria apenas de adicionar uma explicação sobre a sua tentativa (porque ela não funcionou), além de propor algumas alternativas.

Destrinchando a expressão que você usou (`^[:.:]$`):

- `^` e `$` significam, respectivamente, o início e fim da string
- os colchetes (`[]`) delimitam [uma classe (ou conjunto) de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), que faz com que a expressão faça o *match* com uma ocorrência de qualquer caractere que esteja dentro dos colchetes.

Por exemplo, `[ab]` significa: a letra `"a"` **ou** a letra `"b"`. Se eu quiser a letra "a" seguida da letra "b", eu tenho que retirá-las dos colchetes.

Sendo assim, `[:.:]` significa: o caractere `":"` **ou** o caractere `"."` **ou** o caractere `":"` (ou seja, os dois pontos estão redundantes). Dependendo da engine de regex sendo usada, isso pode dar erro (algumas não permitem caracteres repetidos dentro dos colchetes e dão erro, já que isso é redundante).

Outro detalhe é que o ponto (`.`) dentro dos colchetes perde o seu significado especial de "qualquer caractere" e passa a ser somente o próprio "ponto".

Resumindo, a expressão `^[:.:]$` significa "string que possui apenas uma ocorrência de `:` **ou** `.`". Como você usou `^` e `$` para indicar o início e fim da string, a expressão só faz o *match* para strings com um único caractere.

#### Alternativas para a solução

A [solução do #LeAndrade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/312815/112052) parece ser o que você precisa. Mas se quiser refinar um pouco mais a expressão, pode mudá-la de acordo com os seus casos de uso.

Se entre os `:` só podem ter números, eu sugiro mudar o `.` para [atalho](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\d`, ou para `[0-9]` (expressões que [correspondem a qualquer dígito de 0 a 9](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)). Ambas as expressões abaixo fazem isso:

```
:(\d+):
:([0-9]+):
```

Eu também mudei o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*` (zero ou mais ocorrências) para `+` (uma ou mais ocorrências). Usando `*`, há o risco de fazer o *match* com `::` acidentalmente. Usando o `+`, garante que tem que haver pelo menos um dígito.

---

Se podem ter números ou letras, uma alternativa é usar os colchetes colocando estes caracteres dentro. Como vimos no exemplo anterior, é possível definir intervalos de caracteres com o hífen, então a expressão ficaria:

```
// letras maiúsculas, minúsculas, ou dígitos de 0 a 9
:([A-Za-z0-9]+):
```

---

Se puder ter **qualquer coisa** entre os `:`, uma alternativa é usar uma classe de caracteres negada: você pode colocar um `^` dentro dos colchetes, e aí ele passa a fazer *match* com qualquer caractere que **não** esteja dentro deles.

Nesse caso, eu faria `[^:]`, o que quer dizer "qualquer caractere que não seja `:`". A expressão ficaria assim:

```
:([^:]+):
```

Ou seja: "dois pontos, seguido por uma ou mais ocorrências de qualquer caractere que não seja dois pontos, seguido por dois pontos".

---

Claro que você pode usar `.*?` conforme já sugerido. Eu só mudaria para `.+?` para garantir que haja pelo menos um caractere entre os `:`.

Mas se você já sabe quais os valores possíveis (só números, ou letras e números, ou qualquer outra regra) eu sugiro usar uma expressão mais restrita do que `.*`,  para evitar falsos positivos.

E como você mencionou que precisa pegar as posições em que os caracteres aparecem, uma alternativa é usar a [propriedade `index` do objeto retornado por `exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec#Description), que indica a posição em que o *match* foi encontrado:

```js
let texto = "teste :1: e também teste :2:";
let regex = new RegExp(':([^:]+):', 'g');
let result;

while ((result = regex.exec(texto))) {     
    console.log("Encontrado entre os : -> " + result[1]);
    console.log("Posição inicial do : -> " + (result.index));
}
```

Comment: Explicação top man.

Comment: Deu uma aula. Aprendi alguns detalhes interessantes. Top!

Comment: Excelente explicação, muito boa mesmo. Preciso fazer um hackerrank e me deu uma luz.